# De-trend or normalize ordinal data across years

Tags: trend, exploratory-data-analysis

I have multiple years of data from students rating their courses (Unacceptable, Adequate, Good, Excellent). The data covers about 10 courses and I have data from the past 6 years. Charting the data, it seems that some years, classes were just more negative overall. Is there any way to "normalize" or de-trend ordinal data like this to remove the bias introduced by each class of students in order to highlight underlying trends in the performance of the courses?

Comment: I do not think so. These questions require subjective answers from the students.